# Rails Custom Path with Extra Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a custom rails route defined as such:

`resources :scores, path: "seasons/:season_id/scores/:student_id"`

This makes sense for my application and would keep the urls standardized.  This works for the show page and I am able to grab :season_id and :student_id properly.

However, when I try to route to any of the other pages I get errors.  I wanted the new and edit page to be these routes:

**New**

```
resources :scores, path: "seasons/:season_id/scores/:student_id/new"
```

**Edit**

```
resources :scores, path: "seasons/:season_id/scores/:student_id/:id/edit"
```

So they still follow normal conventions, and that's what happens when I run rake routes, but hitting any route throws:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scores", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :season_id=>#<Score id: ... >, :student_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id, :student_id]
```

Which is weird on two accounts.  The season id is being linked to the score object, and it says there are missing keys.  All keys are present in the params hash, and this is how I'm building my links:

```
= link_to "Edit", { controller: :scores, action: :edit, id: score.id, student_id: params[:student_id], season_id: params[:season_id]} , class: "btn btn-success btn-xs"
```

Comment: The error says you are sending action ``"show"``, but the link code you post says ``"edit"``. Can you double check that, or post the exact error that that link produces?

Comment: That's the exact error.  That's why it makes so little sense to me.

I get this as the header: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Scores#edit

With this as the content: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scores", :format=>nil, ..... }

Comment: Does it happen when you click on the link or when you load the page that contains the link?

Comment: Also, why use path, instead of nesting the resource?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? I'm coming from seasons/:season_id where I want the user to be able to click on a score link for a given students. I used path so I could preserve the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better not to use `resources` plus `path` when you need to nest a resource. It's more easy to read and understand, less error prone and it's the Rails convention.

You can write your routes like this:

```
resources :seasons do
  resources :students do
    resources :scores
  end
end
```

And then use the named path method in your link like this:

```
link_to "Edit", edit_score_student_season_path(score, params[:student_id], params[:season_id]), class: "btn btn-success btn-xs"
```

Comment: That creates seasons/:season_id/students/:student_id/scores and then the normal paths after that?

Comment: what do you mean by the "the normal path"?

Comment: Normal resource logic. So the path I posted in my above comment with /new, /id, /id/edit, etc. for the score resources. Additionally. If I nest stuff like this, can I use resources :students on it's own? I can't give up /students as a root page.

Comment: You can run ``rake routes`` and see the results, I believe they will be what you need. And yeah, you can define ``resources :students`` as a root route with no further problem.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help. This seems cleaner than what I was doing. Is what I tried to do even possible, or would I need completely custom routes?

Comment: I never seen resources and paths mixed in that way (there is no need for it!), but I guess you could find a way to make it work ... and still it would smell bad :)